# Why `Could not reach host. Are you offline?` when I call ChromeDriverManager().install() in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My code is belows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager= ChromeDriverManager()
    driver_path=manager.install() # Here is the bug!

    service=service(driver_path)
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

But when i run this, it tells me:

```
Could not reach host. Are you offline?
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "/home/linux/Documents/MyAutomaticPolicy/test_network.py", line 38, in <module>
    driver_path=manager.install()
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?
```

About my network environment:

1. I can use chrome and search any thing.
2. I can use VPN to ping 'googlechromelabs.github.io' and get any.
3. I have tried to run this code with VPN and without VPN.
4. Last night, I run this code successfully……
5. I use `clash`…… And I am thinking that all of these have some relations with `clash`

Comment: Now,it tells me that :
```
  File "/home/linux/anaconda3/envs/MyAutomaticPolicyB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/linux/anaconda3/envs/MyAutomaticPolicyB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/linux/anaconda3/envs/MyAutomaticPolicyB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```